# Basic Angular.js include from tutorial doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a reference to the very basic CodeSchool tutorial for Angular.js. I went through and finished it, thinking I was ready to try it out in a real project. When I use the exact same code as is given in the tutorial, Angular fails to load, producing this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/modulerr?p0=store&p1=Error%3A%…Users%2FJosh%2FDocuments%2FProjects%2Ftimelist%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A139)
```

Here is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);
```

Is this the wrong way to set up a basic Angular project, even though this is what CodeSchool is teaching in its tutorial? Some direction would be good, because I think the issue is in my setup, not the code. Thank you!

Comment: try placing angular.js in the head and check if the angular.min.js file exists

Answer (score 2):

Have you included that app.js file into the html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Please include this line. Hope this help!

Comment: I forgot to put this back into the HTML after I stripped it all down to the bare bones. Angular is loading now and parsing stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks great. Are you sure you installed Angular properly? That seems to be the only problem. Since you're referencing angular.mins.js, make sure that you have angular installed in that same directory as your html and it is indeed called angular.mins.js.

Also, you could try replacing this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

with this one, which is just using a CDN (basically this company already has Angular installed on their servers and you're going to just use theirs)to load Angular.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Also too if that doesn't work make sure you're including your app.js file in your html as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem when copying the official angular example on their frontpage. So for the next ones who can't read like me:

I had

```
html(ng-app="my-app")
```

when it is only

```
html(ng-app)
```